# Need Batch script to search and copy specific file from network drive

Tags: batch-file

I am very new to batch scripting.

I need to write a batch script to search for a specific file(usually .zip or .7z extension) located on network drive directory(containing multiple folder and sub-folders with space in name) and copy the same to my local drive.
Also I need to copy a zip file containing "elf" keyword which will also be located in the same directory where my file is present.

For example:

Search file: abc.zip

Network drive:\abc.com\test

So basically I need to search for my file abc.zip in the network directory(including sub-folders) and if found copy the same to my local drive(say c:\Temp) and also I need to copy *elf* file to the same local directory.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off

    rem Prepare environment
    setlocal enableextensions

    rem Configure paths
    set "source=\abc.com\test"
    set "target=c:\test"

    rem Change drive/path to source of files
    pushd "%source%"

    rem Recurse folders searching adecuated files and when found, copy to target
    for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /s /b "abc.*z*" ^| findstr /i /e /c:".zip" /c:".7z"') do (
        copy /y "%%~ff" "%target%"
        if exist "%%~dpf\*elf*.zip" copy /y "%%~dpf\*elf*.zip" "%target%"
    )

    rem Return to previous drive/path
    popd

    rem Clean
    endlocal
```

This will search the source folder hierarchy for indicated filename and an aproximate match based on file extension (`.*z*` matchs .zip, .7z and more), filters file extensions to only accept the cases needed (.zip and .7z) and copy the required files to target folder.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the Extended Copy Utility (xcopy)? Syntax is as simple as

```
xcopy "<directoryToCopyFrom>" "<directoryToCopyTo>" /C /S /D /Y /I
```

This will work assuming you're wanting to write a Windows batch script.

Searching for the "elf" string will be a bit trickier though. You might consider doing that using Java, and then call the batch file from the Java program.

Answer (score 0):

```
for /d /r "drive:\abc.com\test" %%A in (*) do (
    if exist "%%~A\abc.zip" copy "%%~A\abc.zip" "C:\Temp"
    if exist "%%~A\*elf*" copy "%%~A\*elf*" "C:\Temp"
)
```